# How to add element to Column layout with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, qt, layout, qml

I want to add objects to qml `Column` layout dynamically, but can't figure out how to do this.

So, for simple example, let's assume that we need to add some new object to column by pressing first rectangle. Two others just for some volume.

Here is some code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    visible: true
    id: root


    Item {
        id: itemRef
        width: 310; height: 170

        Column {
            id: columnRef
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            spacing: 5

            Rectangle { color: "lightblue"; radius: 10.0
                        width: 300; height: 50
                        Text { anchors.centerIn: parent
                               font.pointSize: 24; text: "Press me" }
                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: {
                                var component = Qt.createComponent("Sprite.qml");
                                if (component.status === Component.Ready){
                                    sprite = component.createObject(columnRef);
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }
            Rectangle { color: "gold"; radius: 10.0
                        width: 300; height: 50
                        Text { anchors.centerIn: parent
                               font.pointSize: 24; text: "1" } }
            Rectangle { color: "lightgreen"; radius: 10.0
                        width: 300; height: 50
                        Text { anchors.centerIn: parent
                               font.pointSize: 24; text: "2" } }
        }
    }
}
```

And Sprite.qml is just:

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Item {
    Rectangle { width: 300; height: 50; color: "red" }
}
```

I don't want to make it using `listmodel` and `listview`. Is there just simple way  to create item from qml file and then add it to column?

Comment: What is the issue with your code? It looks like it should work.

Comment: @Mitch, oh... well it works but incorrect. The new rectangle appears without any positioning, and if I press the buttoncouple of times then recangles will be placed at the same place but not in column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code:
You are using `sprite` as a variable while its not so defined. It must be declared as `var` in your java script.

Second, Your `sprite.qml` is creating an `Item` which is not expected as child inside your `Column` layout. So you only need to define a `rectangle` inside `sprite.qml`, correcting those issues will render new rectangle as expected

**Bonus**: if you want to render correctly while repeating the clicks, you need to watch the height of your Item container to make sure it can host newly created rectangles. so you can add to your script something like this: `itemRef.height = itemRef.height + sprite.height`

Correct code might look like:

```
...
onClicked: {
    var component;
    var sprite;
    component = Qt.createComponent("Sprite.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready){
        sprite = component.createObject(columnRef);
        itemRef.height = itemRef.height + sprite.height
    }
}
...
```

> and sprite.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
Rectangle { color: "red"; radius: 10.0
            width: 300; height: 50
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent
                   font.pointSize: 24; text: "new" } }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much)

Comment: Also, Sprite.qml with Item works in this way:

Item{
    width: 300; height: 50
    Rectangle { color: "red"; radius: 10.0
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text { anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pointSize: 24; text: "new" } 
    }    
}

I believe it is because I put sizes directly to Item and fill it with rectangle

Comment: Ok, but why you need `Item` at this point .. You already got confused with it.